# (VUE/NODE JS) clicked to do item and store completed status to DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I want TODO list item to be clicked and the status to be stored in database (Mongodb). I am using Vue js and Node js. On a click status changes to "done" (breakthrough line) or "in progress". I get error on network tab: "{"message":"Could not find todo."}". This error comes from backend controller:

```
exports.updateTodo = (req, res, next) => {
  const todoId = req.params.todoId;
  const completed = req.body.completed;
  Todo.findById(todoId)
  .then(todo => {
    if (!todo) {
      const error = new Error('Could not find todo.');
      error.statusCode = 404;
      throw error;
    }
    todo.completed = completed;
    return todo.save();
  })
  .then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Todo updated!', todo: result });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  });
};
```

backend router:

```
router.put('/:todoId', todoController.updateTodo);
```

Frontend template:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div class="todos" id="app">
      <h3 class="todos__title">
        Todo List - VueJS
        <span v-show="itemsTodo.length"> ({{ itemsTodo.length }} pending)</span>
      </h3>
      <input
        class="todos__input"
        type="text"
        @keyup.enter="addTodo"
        v-model="newTodo"
        placeholder="Type and press enter..."
      />
      <ul class="todos__list">
        <li
          class="todos__item"
          v-for="todo in todos"
          :key="todo._id"
          :class="{ todos__completed: todo.completed }"
          @click="todo.completed = !todo.completed; updateTodo(todo)"
          transition="fade"
        >
          <button class="todos__delete" @click.stop="removeTodo(todo._id)">
            &times;</button
          >
          {{ todo.text }}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="todos__empty" v-show="!todos.length">
        Nothing to do... yet!
      </p>
      <a
        class="todos__clear"
        href="#"
        @click.prevent="clearCompleted"
        v-show="itemsDone.length"
        >Clear completed tasks</a
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the updateTodo method:

```
 updateTodo(todo) {
      const todoStatus = { completed: todo.completed };
      axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/todos/${todo._id}`, todoStatus)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    },
```

On the model schema of the backend configuration:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const todoSchema = new Schema({
 text: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 completed: {
  type: Boolean
 }
},
{ timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todos', todoSchema);
```

Error in node js terminal:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide output of `todo` from server ?

Comment: I can add a new todo item and it appears on the screen and is stored to the server. Error in terminal of node js I will edit the post in a moment.

Comment: Noo, add `console.log(todo)` before `if (!todo)` row and show output

Comment: Now is working, just figured out myself. Issue was in Vue updateTodo method within axios response. I addeda code: "const todo = {
          _id: resData.todo._id,
          completed: resData.todo.completed,
        }
        return todo;"
THANK YOU very much for your help and time!

Comment: Don’t include solutions in the question section - instead, post as a self-answer below to make the solution more visible to future visitors to this question and to better adhere to Stack Overflow’s Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED UPDATE:**
The issue was in Vue side of axios response, I added this code:

```js
const todo = {
  _id: resData.todo._id,
  completed: resData.todo.completed,
}
return todo;
```

### Hope will help someone one day!